# Fisher Score Feature Selection Implementation

Tags: feature-selection

I am trying to implement the Fisher Scoring Algorithm for feature selection. From "Data Classification: Algorithms and Applications":

On Page 44:

> The score of the i-th feature $S_i$ will be calculated by Fisher Score,
>   $\ S_i = \frac{\sum n_j(\mu_{ij}-\mu_i)^2}{\sum n_j * \rho_{ij}^2} $ where $\mu_{ij}$ and $\rho_{ij}$ are the mean and the variance of the i-th feature in the j-th class, respectivly, $n_j$ is the number of instances in the j-th class and $\mu_{i}$ is the mean of the i-th feature.

When searching for examples or implementations, I could not find any. So I wrote something myself, but I dont know if itˋs correct. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could tell me if my implementation is correct.

Here is the code in julia, I am using the Iris dataset:

```
# Required module: RDataset
using RDatasets

# load dataset, turn data into Array, because by default is loaded
# as a dataframe
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris") |> Array

# Turn values into Float64 
iris[:,1:4] = map(Float64, iris[:, 1:4])

# Get different classes of the response variable
class = unique(iris[:, 5])

# Calculate the mean of each feature = $\mu_{i}$
fmean = map(mean, [iris[:, i] for i=1:4]) 

# Seperate the data into nclasses
classes = [iris[ iris[:, 5] .== class[i], j] for i=1:3, j=1=4] 

# Calculate $\mu_{ij}$
mu = map(mean, classes)

# And $\rho_{ij} 
rho = map(var, classes)

# Set $\n_j$
n = [50, 50, 50]

# Do the calculation according to the formula    
numerator = [ [l[j] * (mu[j,i] - fmean[i])^2 for j=1:3] |> sum for i=1:4]     

denominator = [ [l[j] * rho[j, i]^2 for j=1:3] |> sum for i=1:4]     

# Return
numerator ./ denominator
```

Comment: I think this is off topic.

Comment: offtopic or not it should be mentioned that rho_ij in the literature citation should either be (rho_ij)^2 OR it should be the standard deviation if I am not mistaken. That would make more sense to me; e.g. free literature stating the same: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.3725.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open source implementation for fisher score](https://github.com/jundongl/scikit-feature).

(There is also a [tutorial for feature selection](http://featureselection.asu.edu/tutorial.php).)

And for your question, I am not familiar with julia. But I recommend you to use the above library to see whether the results are the same.

I also attach my simple and crude implementation of fisher score for two classes in matlab as an example.

```
mu = mean(feature);

n_1 = sum(label == 1);
mu_1 = mean(feature(label == 1));
var_1 = var(feature(label == 1));

n_2 = sum(label == 2);
mu_2 = mean(feature(label == 2));
var_2 = var(feature(label == 2));

inter_class = n_1*(mu_1-mu)^2 + n_2*(mu_2-mu)^2; 
intra_class = (n_1-1)*var_1 + (n_2-1)*var_2;

score = inter_class / intra_class;
```